# How can I get the Windows 8 Phone emulator to run via VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone, virtualbox, windows-phone-8-emulator

First I'm not sure my computer can handle the VirtualBox and Windows 8 phone emulator because there is no button for the run emulator.

Is there a certain requirement I need to run the emulator for Windows Phone 8 and VirtualBox?

Comment: Do you have the home version of Windows?

Comment: I have the Windows 8 Enterprise Developer Build that Microsoft allows developers to have for 90 days.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copy the Flash.vhd from an installed Windows Phone 8 SDK and use it as the virtual disk in VirtualBox with the guest configured for Windows 8. It works for me with a Mac host, but I have an invisible mouse pointer so interaction is difficult.

Comment: Were you able to enable the keyboard?

Comment: And how do you install an application to such emulator?

Answer (score 1):

The hardware emulation requirements are found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Here is a brief summary from that documentation:

> Quick checklist
>
> Here is a quick checklist of the requirements for running the Windows
>   Phone 8 Emulator. For more detailed info, see the subsequent sections
>   in this topic.
>
> System requirements
>
> - In the BIOS, the following features must be supported:
>
>   - Hardware-assisted virtualization.
>   - Second Level Address Translation (SLAT).
>   - Hardware-based Data Execution Prevention (DEP).
> - 4 GB or more of RAM.
> - 64-bit version of Windows 8 Pro edition or higher.
>
> Network requirements
>
> - DHCP.
> - Automatically configured DNS and gateway settings.
>
> Hyper-V requirements
>
> - In the BIOS, the following features must be enabled:
>
>   - Hardware-assisted virtualization.
>   - Second Level Address Translation (SLAT).
>   - Hardware-based Data Execution Prevention (DEP).
> - In Windows, Hyper-V must be enabled and running.
> - You have to be a member of the local Hyper-V Administrators group.

Comment: I suggest checking Hyper-V next

Comment: I have a late 2009 iMac.  Do you think that it should run okay? Graphics  ATI Radeon HD 4850 512 MB, Memory  4 GB 1067 MHz DDR3, Processor  2.66 GHz Intel Core i5

Comment: I really can't tell you.  You need to go through the checklist I linked, and see if your computer meets all the (mostly software) requirements.  You might just have a few things turned off.

Comment: When I did the computer grading it said my graphics card was not fast enough or something.

Comment: Is.. the graphics card a big part of the emulator?

Comment: No, it has pretty much nothing to do with it.  If you won't use the step-by-step help document I found for you, then there is nothing I can help you with.  READ IT!

Comment: I only asked about the Graphics part because I had some windows warning while running it, thanks for your help.