# Enabling Hyper V in Control Panel

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

I want to test Windows phone 8 App in my Windows 8 system using Visual studio ultimate 2013. I checked few tutorials on net to enable Hyper V in my system. I found that below requirements are enabled in my system.

```
 Hyper-V Requirements: VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                       Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                       Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                       Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

But the problem is that I am not able to see Hyper V option in control panel under "Turn windows feature on or off ". Can someone please tell me what could be the reason for this and how can I find that option in control panel?

Below is the system Info-

```
    OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 8
    OS Version:                6.2.9200 N/A Build 9200
    OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
    OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
    OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free

    Registered Organization:   Toshiba

   Original Install Date:     9/9/2013, 10:02:15 PM
   System Boot Time:          11/28/2013, 5:07:46 AM
   System Manufacturer:       TOSHIBA
   System Model:              Satellite C55t-A
   System Type:               x64-based PC
   Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                       [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9 GenuineInt
                             el ~1900 Mhz
   BIOS Version:              Insyde Corp. 1.20, 6/7/2013
   Windows Directory:         C:\windows
   System Directory:          C:\windows\system32
   Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume2
   System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
  Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
  Time Zone:                 (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)
  Total Physical Memory:     3,975 MB
  Available Physical Memory: 2,561 MB
  Virtual Memory: Max Size:  4,679 MB
  Virtual Memory: Available: 3,199 MB
```

Comment: what is your pc configuration

Comment: added system info in the question...Hope this will help in answering it.

Comment: Do you have Win 8 Professional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [blog](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/extremewindows/archive/2013/06/20/hyper-v-support-in-windows-8.aspx).
Do you have Windows 8 Pro or Enterprise 64 bit Operating System? If you don't have - probably you won't be able to run hyper V - only client version.

Comment: hmm...I found what was my system lacking... I have only Windows 8(basic) edition. I will be upgrading it to PRO soon. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That was the reason why I've upgraded to PRO version :)

Comment: @Romasz Hi, Without upgrading to Pro anyway to Run the Emulator ?

Comment: @Eldho Emulator runs with HyperV which is not available in basic OS. Though you may try to run emulator on VirtualBox https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=55070 and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WANk_XaovqM But it's hard for me to say if it will work and how. I decided to use HyperV

Comment: @Eldho There is also a question here on stack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489555/how-can-i-get-the-windows-8-phone-emulator-to-run-via-virtualbox

Comment: Thank you, i will try with that .My pc has only 4 gb ram so might experience bad performance if i virtual do it.   @Romasz

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled Hyper V in BIOS options?
If not go to BIOS and enable there and then you can test your app. That was the only thing that i had to do

Comment: If I can see all the 4 options set to yes in my Systeminfo, Do I still need to enable them in BIOS settings ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Because like i said, i only enabled Hyper V in bios - and all works fine. You should check it out