# Anyways of running app without requiring Windows 8 Pro version

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, winjs, win-universal-app

I have been using Windows 8.1 for creating Windows Store apps. Below is output of winver command.

[image]

I have installed necessary updates to start developing universal Windows Store app using JavaScript. When I try to launch app on Windows Phone emulator, I am getting following error.

> Unable to start windows phone emulator

It also suggesting to use Windows 8 pro version. Is there anyway of running this without requiring to throw more money on getting Windows 8 Pro version?

Comment: Emulator uses Hyper-V which is available with Win8 pro. Once I've read about VirtualBox (thought I haven't tried this), but you may try: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16489555/2681948), [two](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=55070), [three](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WANk_XaovqM).

Comment: This question is asked every month or so here. :) Options are to upgrade or to buy an inexpensive physical phone.

Comment: @Romasz thanks for helpful link. That actually helps. Not sure how can I mark you comments as answer unless you put it in the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone Emulator requires Hyper-V which needs Windows Pro version. That's probably why you aren't able to start your Emulator.

As I've posted in comment, I've heard about VirtualBox and an ability to run WP Emulator on it. Some helpful links: [other question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16489555/2681948), [VirtualBox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=55070), [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WANk_XaovqM). I'm not sure how it will work (and if) as I haven't tried this.

IMO I would follow WiredPrairie's comment - upgrade or buy inextensive phone.