# Run windows phone emulator 8 or 8.1 without using Hyper-v

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, hyper-v

As you know , for running  wp8.X emulator , hyper-v is necessary and this feature is on windows 8.X pro version . so now i have windows 8.1 standard . i wanna know is there any solution for that , without buying windows 8.X  pro version . for example is it possible to use virtualbox instead of using hyper-v or ... ???

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anyways of running app without requiring windows 8 Pro version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23459173/anyways-of-running-app-without-requiring-windows-8-pro-version)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows Phone 8 emulator is a special `Hyper-V` image.

you can use a virtual machine to deploy windows phone 8 OS. My laptop processor does not support hyper-v so, I've installed win phone 8 on a virtual machine. I found this link helpful.. check it out:  [How to use Windows Phone 8 Emulator without Hyper-V](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WANk_XaovqM)

Comment: Thank you . but if you are wp developer and you want to test your windows phone application , what do you do ?

Comment: That YouTube video link is gone/down now :(

Answer (score 5):

If you want to develop apps without using a pro version of windows and Hyper-V you can deploy your apps to a physical device.