# test windows Phone web application on Windows 7 or 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, web-applications

> I have problem. I create web application for windows phone and i need
>   to test this app. **How i can test when my PC does not support
>   Hyper-V** ?  Thanks for answer :)

Comment: Are you sure that, it doesn't support your pc or have you not enable it? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: yes i try it and my Bios does not support this setting :)

Comment: I've post the alternatives below, which has already been given.

Answer (score 1):

In case if your PC does not support `Hyper-V`, try installing it within a `Virtual Machine`. References:

- [Run windows phone emulator 8 or 8.1 without using Hyper-v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057667/)
- [Windows phone emulator doesn't run without Hyper V on Win 8.1....any alternative emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296797/)