# Windows Phone 8 emulator on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

Is it possible to run Windows Phone 8 emulator on Windows 8.1 standard edition (not 8.1 Pro)?

I know that normally the emulator requires Hyper-V which is not available in non-Pro version but since Windows Phone 7 emulator works fine without Hyper-V maybe there is a way to run 8's emulator without Hyper-V as well?

Comment: Maybe one of the solutions provided to former questions will help: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24057667/2681948), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22296797/2681948) and [three](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23459173/2681948).